# How to ask this question, which has a 7-year-old duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I want to post a question about creating a "game UI" with javascript and HTML5 canvas. I'm not sure how to keep it on topic because

- It's basically a recommendation question,
- [It's already been asked and answered here.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/html5-game-canvas-ui-techniques/7115)

The existing question was asked 7 years ago (active 4 years ago) and the web has changed since then. Is it appropriate to ask the same or similar question now?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "the web bas changed since then" statement. Today's standards came out a while ago and the answer doesn't depend on versions either. And yes, it will probably be closed if you don,'t have specific stuff in mind.

Comment: @Bálint Was being vague here because I don't know the exact history, but HTML5 has evolved from a living standard to w3c 5.1 and browser support is more consistent with WebGL.

Comment: This is why I think questions grounded in or about the timeliness of technology shouldn’t be on-topic here in the first place :(

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, rephrase your question so it’s more narrowly focused on a specific technique and a problem you’re having with it, or similar. Something like “I tried this, I wanted this result, I got this instead, what can I do about it?”

As long as you're not asking for broad lists of techniques or unfocused strategies or technology recommendations, you can probably phrase a question that isn’t a clear duplicate of the above.

In the worst case scenario, you ask it, it gets duped, and we can figure out how to edit your specific question to make it unique.

Answer (score 3):

You should start a bounty on the question.

Bounties are there to bring attention to the question, and you don't have to be the one who asked the question to start a bounty on it.

When you start the bounty, you have to specify why you start it, and there is a reason with your context: *Current answers are outdated -- The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.*

[image]

Once you've selected the reason why you start a bounty, you can also specify a custom message (3000 characters) to add more details about why you start it and what you're after (keep in mind that the new answers will still have to answer the question).

[image]

You will not be able to change the accepted answer, but you'll be able to give the bounty to the most helpful answer.